# Datasource healthcheck frequency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

I am using Spring Boot Actuator (2.1.4.Release version) for Spring Boot Admin features. There are a lot of operations with different databases in my project and all was working well for a long time. 
But recently we got a message from our Teradata datasource provider that we spam them with a lot of "Select 1" queries (db connection status as i understand). From **DataSourceHealthIndicator** class in `org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc` i can see `DEFAULT_QUERY = "SELECT 1"` and methods in which this query is done, but i can't find information about the frequency of this query, also there is no logging for it.

Now i used `management.health.db.enabled=false` property to turn off this spam, but i want to know, how to tune it?

In a good day there were one `Select` per 30 sec, but it sometimes gone mad and exceeded to 200 queries per minute that sums to hundred thousands of selects in a day. It is worth mention that this behavior somehow connects to a new application release time, where application could be stopped/restarted, because after this period Selects "goes mad". Maybe we could change frequency of this queries?